# Load Joomla module inside alternative layout

Tags: php, joomla

I have created an alternative layout for the blog articles view. I would like to load a module inside this layout if the module is published, something like I do in the index.php with:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('breadcrumb')) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main-slider" style="none" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code does not work in the alternative layout .php file. How should I modify the code to display the module inside that page, only if the module is published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this way, example:

```
<?php if($modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('sidebar')) : ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $secclassr; ?>">
        <?php
            $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('sidebar');

            foreach ($modules as $module)
            {
                echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );//call module helper class
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('main-slider');//call the module
foreach ($modules as $module){
   echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);//display it
}
```